# Floating images with multiple sizes in CSS

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I'm wanting to be able to create a banner of floating images based on what are uploaded via users.  The tool needs to have images of 50x50 and 100x100.  At the moment, I just want to randomly display the images and tried to apply float:left.  However, as you can see below - it leaves gaps.

Is there an easy way to do this without programatically positioning the images?
[image: example]

If you want the code so far, it's here:

```
.wall {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    display: table;
}

.wall img {

    float: left;

}
```

and

```
<div class="wall">
    <img src="man1.png" alt=""/>
    <!-- ETC... !-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to write some code. The first thing that I notice is that the gaps are all fillable by a 50x50 (the smallest) image. I would try implementing the following:

1. Fill the page with 50x50 images randomly.
2. Absolutely position a few 100x100 images. These will cover 4 underlying 100x100 images.

Seems like this will work (haven't tried), but hopefully that helps.

Bob

Comment: I like the idea behind this but it's not really going to work for me.  I need all images to be displayed in this banner, so overing 4 of the smaller ones up with the one large one will mean some of the images won't be visible to the user.  Thanks for the suggestion though! :)